# Getting a list iterator via reference to an element in the list

Tags: c++, list, reference, iterator, listiterator

In C++ coding:
Lets say I have a function that returns a reference to an element in a certain list (i cannot change the return type or what the function does).
Is there any way, via that returned **reference**, that i can get the **iterator** to that specific element on that list?
Thanks,
Roy

Comment: The referenced object does not know that it is part of a list

Comment: Take a look at [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: If you don't have access to the list itself, no. If you do, you can  `std::find` the element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do that in **unsafe** manner, with assumption that `std::list<T>::iterator` implemented as a pointer to a list node. Basically you need adjust address of your value to get an address of enclosing list node, and that would be iterator's value.

[image]

Actual code (works with gcc and clang on mac):

```
// Offset may vary for different Ts
template <typename T>
std::ptrdiff_t list_node_payload_offset() {
    std::list<T> lst;
    lst.push_back(T{});
    auto lst_begin = lst.begin();
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(std::addressof(lst.front())) -
        *reinterpret_cast<uint8_t**>(std::addressof(lst_begin));
}

#pragma GCC optimize "no-strict-aliasing"
template <typename T>
typename std::list<T>::iterator to_list_iterator(T& t) {
    static const auto offset = list_node_payload_offest<T>();
    auto node_address = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(std::addressof(t)) - offset;
    return *reinterpret_cast<typename std::list<T>::iterator*>(&iter_value);
}
#pragma GCC optimize "strict-aliasing"
```

[<kbd>On Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb43cce15047b633)

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have access to the list. This should be a given if you are intending to use the iterator anyway.

You will have to iterate the list again, and check each element returned by the iterator until you match the given reference.